# Pointwise limit of functions bounded in $L^1$

Tags: real-analysis

If $f_n$ is a sequence of functions which converges pointwise to $f$ almost everywhere, and there is a constant $c > 0$ such that $\|f_n\|_{L^1} \leq c$ for all $n$, then is it true that $f \in L^1(\mathbb R)$?

Comment: See [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fatou%27s_lemma).

Comment: @DavidMitra Oh of course! Thanks.